# Google Analytics Metadata API Identify valid combinations

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to identify valid combinations of dimensions and metrics using the Google Analytics Metadata API?

Something similar to the functionality of this tool:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Answer (score 0):

No. I'm sure we cannot do this (although it would be great), partly because it is not in the documentation and party because you can inspect the [complete output of the metadata API in the browser](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns?pp=1). Big JSON  thingy without any information about valid combinations. So I guess it's safe to say we cannot.